Does Partial Correlation Affect Likelihood of Multivariate Normal?
Suppose I have a 3-dimensional multivariate normal distribution characterized by the following variance-covariance matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{X} & C_{XY} & C_{XZ} \\
C_{XY} & V_{Y} & C_{YZ} \\
C_{XZ} & C_{YZ} & V_{Z} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My question is that ...
surely there exists a partial correlation, also known as the conditional covariance, $Cov(X,Y|Z)$.  And yet, given some data, if we want to find the maximum likelihood value of our parameters, none of the parameters in the matrix above are partial correlations implying the partial correlation does not affect the likelihood.  I suppose I am willing to accept this because perhaps you could argue that an entire range of possible partial correlations are wholly compatible with the data.  But at the same time, if I ran a regression of $Y$ ~ $Z$ and of $X$ ~ $Z$ and then ran a regression of $residuals(Y ~ Z)$ ~ $residuals(X ~ Z)$ I would get some value for the partial correlation, and I would get a p-value for the regression telling me the strength of evidence for the partial correlation.  But then if the partial correlation does have an optimal value which maximizes the likelihood of the data, how do I find it by maximum likelihood, because the likelihood seems to be independent of the partial correlations?

You lost me at "implying," because your conclusion is mathematically false.  The duplicate shows explicitly how to use the covariance matrix to perform the regression.

I came up with this answer that I think is correct.  Simply parameterize the precision matrix as is seen  fit, and then construct from that the covariance matrix to calculate the likelihood.  This way you can get the likelihood of the distribution specified by the precision matrix. (see https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/normal_markov_chain.html for details)
